# Creating seamless/uniform topography with multiple raster tiles?

Tags: qgis, raster, dem, tiles, topography

I have multiple elevation raster tiles of an archaeological site and it would be extremely useful for me to visualize the topography as one 'uniform' image/layer. I have attempted to merge the rasters, build a virtual raster, and copy/paste the style from one layer to others, yet I have been unable to produce a seamless image from any of the said methods.

[image: Example of two of the tiles]

The tiles overlap considerably, most more so than the two tiles in the example. I have checked the elevations between layers of some of the overlapping areas and they appear to match, so the problem doesn't seem to be incongruous elevation data.

When I have copy and pasted styles I have made sure to change the elevation data to the min/max values among the tiles and as well as make sure the break values also match. Yet, inconceivably, this makes it worse.

[image]

Comment: Check all images for min/max-values, write them down. Then classify one image using these boundaries and sensible breaks. Copy the style to all the other images.

Comment: I should have elaborated; I did indeed check and use the min/max values when copying/pasting styles from a layer to others, yet it did not produce the desired effect, though I admit I do not know what sensible breaks would be.

Comment: If all images had the same style, especially the same classes/breaks based on the overall min/max values, there'd be no discontinuity. Sensible classes/breaks for DEM would be a different colour every 10 m e.g.

Comment: Good morning LCorvino! I learned the hard way that QGIS lists *estimated* min/max values by default.  I wonder if that could be the source of your problem?  Try changing min/max to *actual* values. See my earlier SE question at: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/321408/qgis-vrt-values-differ-from-the-source-rasters

Comment: Can you share what settings you used for merge?   Are you getting an error, or is it producing a valid output that isn't what you're looking for? Could you post example files?  This is exactly what merge is supposed to do, and I've used it in the past.