# Merge raster data

Tags: qgis, raster, merge, elevation, minimum-mapping-unit

I merged four rasters using raster>miscellaneous> merge. (I did not specify any not data values. and it is set as 'Not set').
When I check my four separate rasters, elevation ranges are -6.6 to 64.4 (considering all). But in the merged raster it is -7.66 to 62.98. Why is there this difference? How exactly does this merge work scientifically? Is it using resampling or any other interpolation methods?

Comment: An explanation would be easier if you [Edit] the question to provide extents and pixel sizes for the rasters involved.

Comment: I have had a similar problem, which can be viewed at: **https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/321408/qgis-vrt-values-differ-from-the-source-rasters**.  Basically, the problem was that the raster's statistics were *estimated*, rather than *actual*.

Comment: pixel sizes would be 0.4m*0.4m and extents are 30km*40km. I just did a rough overview, before I resample, and that raised these questions.